# Hashmaps and keeping time complexity low

Tags: hashmap, time-complexity

I have a list of words, and a lot of posts. I have to check if any of those words are present in the post, if so, save it, and then go to the next, and so on.

I can change the list of n words in an hashmap so when I'll check I'll have O(1), but I have still to go through all the words in the single post [O(n)], and then to all the posts [O(n^2)].

Any suggestion to improve this?

Usually I wouldn't bother, but the number of posts is massive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's mostly right. You can't beat `O(n + m)` where `n` is the number of words in all of the posts and `m` is the length of target words. We assume `O(1)` to look up each word in the set/hash of target words `m` and `O(m)` to build the set.

But `O(nn)` doesn't look right because the size of the posts isn't quadratic and there's no relationship between the number of words in posts and the number of posts.

You could call it `O(num_target_words + num_posts * max(num_words_in_post))` but this seems like an awkard way to characterize the problem that's mostly dependent on words, not on posts. So just `O(n + m)` seems clearest.

If `m` is constant and/or the set construction is guaranteed non-expensive, we can disregard it and just call it `O(n)`. But maybe you have a huge bucket of potential words and just a few posts, in which case `m` dominates.